# GA Cross Domain Tracking for subfolders with different UA-ID

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, analytics, subdirectory, referrer

Our site is broken down into 4 main subfolders lets say **www.site.com/a/**, **www.site.com/b/**, **www.site.com/c/** and **www.site.com/d/**.

Each of those subfolders has a different Google Analytics tracking account because we treat those subfolders as different divisions.

We want to be able to track clicks from **www.site.com/a/mypage.html** to **www.site.com/b/yourpage.html**.

Because they have different tracking codes the clicks between divisions don't carry over between GA accounts. So when the page www.site.com/b/yourpage.html has stats the referrer is {not set} and the previous page path is set to {entrance}, even though they should be www.site.com/a/mypage.html.

It was suggested, during the creation of our GA accounts to put our domain **site.com** in the Referral Exclusion List to avoid new sessions being created but I'm wondering if this is what is causing the clicks to not detect the previous page or referrer page, because we are excluding it.

Can anyone help me figure out how I am going to track these stats?

Is using cross domain tracking an option, even though we're not changing domains?

Any help on this will be a big help. TIA

Comment: see stackoverflow guidelines. thanks

Comment: Muhammad can you tell me what I did wrong...?

Answer (score 0):

The exclusion from the referral is certainly what makes the direct traffic result, however it is correct that it is set like this. The main problem is that track the same site by dividing the sections into 4 different Analytics Properties is not a good practice.

Cross-domain tracking will not work because they are different Properties (unless you have GA360).

However you can get what you need by using the **UTMs** parameters on the links, for example for a link from site A to site B you will have to write the URL of the link like this:

```
www.site.com/b/yourpage.html?utm_source=fromA&utm_medium=referral
```

In reports you will see these values ​​in referral channel with the defined source instead of direct traffic.